# How do I get specific rows once prioritized from multiple tabs to copy onto the 1st tab/worksheet?

Tags: excel, tabs, excel-2007

I have created an excel workbook with 11 tabs/sheets.  The first sheet is a combined prioritization preceding the 10 individual department prioritizations each on their own sheet.  I used the same column headers on all of the 11 sheets, with column A being "Division Priority".  What i'm trying to do is when any row is updated with a number in column A on any of the 10 tabs, the row is copied to the first tab/sheet which is the "consolidated" tab. For example, on sheet 3 for sales and marketing, that team places a 3 in column A for one of the projects, it would now show on Tab 1- 'Consolidated'  I'm a beginner and have been searching for hours on how to do this including using some IF statements but nothing seems to be specific to a column while copying the row or limiting the data that is transferred to the master sheet to only specific rows after they have been numbered.  any help is much appreciated.  Or any other specific questions just let me know.

**Addendum from comment:**

I want any row that is designated with a number in column A on any of the tabs (2-11) to show up on the first tab. So if on tab/sheet 3, the sales team decides the project listed in row 15 is their #1 priority, they would put a '1' in column A row 15. That would copy that entire row onto the first tab/sheet as it's the consolidated project list of priorities (so sheet 3 row 15 would be copied to sheet 1, row 2). Anything not numbered in column A would therefore not show on the first tab/sheet.

Comment: Do you want to update a row in the first worksheet or add the new value (and possibly more information) to the first blank row on the first worksheet? Your question may be clear in your mind but it is decidedly vague from mine. Can't program vague.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I want any row that is designated with a number in column A on any of the tabs (2-11) to show up on the first tab.  So if on tab/sheet 3, the sales team decides the project listed in row 15 is their #1 priority, they would put a '1' in column A row 15. That would copy that entire row onto the first tab/sheet as it's the consolidated project list of priorities (so sheet 3 row 15 would be copied to sheet 1, row 2).  Anything not numbered in column A would therefore not show on the first tab/sheet.  i don't know if that clarified it or made it more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a `Workbook_SheetChange` that will cover all of the worksheets (excluding the first) that will act on a change to a numeric value in columns A.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, look to the *Project Explorer* on the left side. If you cannot find the Project Explorer, tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to show it (or View ► Project Explorer). Double-click *ThisWorkbook* to show the workbook code sheet. Paste the following into the pane on the right side titled something like *Book1 - ThisWorkbook (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row > 1 And Sh.Index > 1 And _
          IsNumeric(Target) And Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            On Error GoTo Fìn
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Resize(1, Target.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s). Any number typed into column A of worksheets 2-12 will result in that row being copied to the first worksheet's first blank row.

**EDIT: Add project removal when priority is removed**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Row > 1 And Sh.Index > 1 And _
          IsNumeric(Target) And Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            On Error GoTo Fìn
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Resize(1, Target.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ElseIf Target.Row > 1 And Sh.Index > 1 And _
          (IsEmpty(Target) Or Not IsNumeric(Target)) Then
            On Error GoTo Fìn
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Sheets(1)
                If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Columns(3), Target.Offset(0, 2).Value)) Then
                    .Rows(Application.Match(Target.Offset(0, 2).Value, .Columns(3), 0)).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The above will look in the first worksheet for the project identifier associated with the project in column C when the priority is removed from the division worksheet. If the priority is changed from something like *3* to *1*, it will still make a duplicate record. That scenario has not been fully accounted for as there has been no discussion on business rules for dealing with it.

Comment: @ProjAnalys29 - Glad that worked out for you. The workbook-wide event macro could be modified to remove entries from the first worksheet when a project was downgraded but some unique identifier such as a project number would have to be used to locate the entry from the first worksheet in order to remove it.

Comment: so I do have each project identified in column C of each of the sheets by a project number.  We use an internal program for project tracking so the column is actually called "Praxis".  Would that be an identifier that could be used to add that functionality to the macro? Either way, again thanks for the help

Comment: @ProjAnalys29 - please see the addendum I've added

Comment: So the sheet has grown and I now have 16 tabs, 15 rolling up to that first tab (consolidated).  so a few of the tabs arent rolling up now.  My question is what portion of the macro is controlling the amount of worksheets to reference?  that way i can edit it to include the additional worksheets and i don't have to ask for help if it grows again?  Let me know your thoughts. and thanks again.